# How to get the length of the array datatypes in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I could get the length, precision and scale of the Postgres Datatypes as below,

```
  SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type, c.character_maximum_length, c.numeric_precision
  c.numeric_scale, e.data_type AS element_type 
  FROM information_schema.columns c  
  LEFT JOIN information_schema.element_types e 
  ON ((c.table_catalog, c.table_schema, c.table_name, 'TABLE', c.dtd_identifier) = 
  (e.object_catalog, e.object_schema, e.object_name, e.object_type, 
  e.collection_type_identifier)) 

   WHERE c.table_schema ='Schema' AND c.table_name ='Table'
```

But some how I could not get the length, precision and scale for all the Array Datatypes like CHAR[], BIT VARYING[], VARCHAR[] and so on.

I was almost through in getting the Array Datatypes properly with the help of element_types but that view does not help me in getting the lenght, precision and scales of the Array Datatypes.

Please let me know our comments on the same.

Note : Am using Postgres 9.2

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do in practice?

Comment: Am creating a table1, with column1 and column2 with datatype as char(5) and char(12)[] and hence my DDL looks like this            CREATE TABLE "Schema2"."Table1" (
    "Column1" CHAR(5),
  "Column2" CHAR(12)[ ] );                                                                Now am trying to get back the values from the catalog tables of Postgres. Where i could succeed getting the value of char(5), but not for the character array char(12)[]. Which catalog table/view stores that info....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, it worked for me

```
mickey=# CREATE TABLE Table1 ( Column1 CHAR(5), Column2 CHAR(12)[ ] );
CREATE TABLE
mickey=# \d table1

Table "public.table1"
 Column  |      Type       | Modifiers 
---------+-----------------+-----------
 column1 | character(5)    | 
 column2 | character(12)[] | 

mickey=# SELECT 
col_attr.attname as "ColumnName", 
pg_catalog.format_type(col_attr.atttypid, col_attr.atttypmod) as "DataType" 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute col_attr 
WHERE 
col_attr.attnum > 0 AND NOT col_attr.attisdropped 
AND col_attr.attrelid = ( SELECT cls.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class cls LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = cls.relnamespace WHERE cls.relname = 'table1');

 ColumnName |    DataType     
------------+-----------------
 column1    | character(5)
 column2    | character(12)[]
(2 rows)

mickey=#
```

Comment: Thanks Parthi, your queries were helpful in achieving my task. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your comment... You can identify this information using psql.

Run psql with the -E or --echo-hidden option, so it outputs hidden system queries that it runs in the background:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Then run \d yourtable (or \d+ yourtable). It'll show you precisely which pg_catalog tables contain what information, including the ones that store the details on array types.